# mono to run on windows

Tags: mono, window

**mono 3.2**

How to run simple hello form in windows. When I run "mono" command it gives following error. I have already fixed .config file in mono installation folder.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.

  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt16 (System.Object ptr, Int32 ofs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Drawing.Font.FromLogFont (System.Object lf, IntPtr hdc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Drawing.Font.FromHfont (IntPtr hfont) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Windows.Forms.Theme.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Font () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at hello.Form1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) hello.Form1:.ctor ()

  at hello.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.

  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt16 (System.Object ptr, Int32 ofs) 

[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Drawing.Font.FromLogFont (System.Object lf, IntPtr hdc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Drawing.Font.FromHfont (IntPtr hfont) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Windows.Forms.Theme.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Font () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at hello.Form1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) hello.Form1:.ctor ()

  at hello.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

It is simple form in winforms with .net framework 3.5

Comment: why do you need mono for windows? Mono's biggest point is to be able to use .NET **outside** Windows

Comment: Yes but I want to do coding and testing on windows machine